# "trick" someone into loving you

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering if there's an English expression for *making someone fall in love with you*.

In Hungarian there is a term that could be translated into something like "fooling someone into yourself" - meaning you make the person fall deep in love with you, and it is implied that it's thanks to some deceitful or dishonest behavior.

Comment: [One of these?](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=seduce)

Comment: As tchrist suggests, "seduce" has something of the sense you imply.  If you look at some of it's [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/seduce) you may find a word more to your liking.  But the area is a bit of a minefield, with many different nuances.

Comment: I guess *beguile* might have a similar meaning. Seduce in my understanding does not necessarily have a negative connotation - while the expression I am looking for definitely implies that you lose control over yourself (become a fool.)

Comment: *Seduce* has a definite negative connotation.  The point that may make it unsuited for your needs is that it doesn't imply causing the seduced party to "fall in love", but rather is usually taken to mean enticing the seduced party into having sex, without first achieving a condition of mutual romantic love.

Answer (score 1):

To [**philter**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/philter): from the

> potion, charm, or drug supposed to cause the person taking it to fall
>   in love, usually with some specific person.

and used as a verb:

> to enchant or bewitch with a philter

Answer (score 1):

A suitor can win/capture/steal someone's heart.

> **win someone's heart** and **win the heart of someone**
>
> Fig. to gain the affection of someone; to win the love of someone exclusively.
> *I hope to win her heart and make her my bride*.
> — [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/win+heart).

> **steal someone's heart**.
>
> Fig. to capture someone's affections; to cause someone to fall in love with oneself. 
> *When I first met him, I knew he would steal my heart away. And he did.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd associate this with being a heart-breaker or a player, mainly because lack of emotional involvement on the side of the perpetrator is implied.

being a *heartbreaker*

> A person who is very attractive but who is irresponsible in emotional relationships:
>   *'he was such a heartbreaker, charming and incorrigible'*

he played her|she player him
*player*

> A male who is skilled at manipulating ("playing") others, and especially at seducing women by pretending to care about them, when in reality they are only interested in sex.

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heartbreaker
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=player

Comment: Your example of a *heartbreaker* doesn't seem to fit the OP's request - they want something that connotes trickery not just breaking someone's heart.

Comment: But *play* works.

Answer (score -2):

**Seduce**

> 2. To persuade or induce to have sexual intercourse.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/seduce?s=t))